# Typing in any Text Field crashes app

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason whenever I add a text field to my project and try type in it, the app crashes.

The errors I get are:

```
Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 1336863583_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1018b1d80

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1018b1d80'
```

This happens in both the simulator and on device. I have unchecked "Connect Hardware Keyboard" in the simulator settings also.

Do I have to handle each and every input?

Comment: provide some code how you are adding the textfield

Comment: All in storyboard @NeilGaliaskarov

Comment: do you assign the delegate of textfield?

Comment: what is the type of textfield?

Comment: Change your keyboard type. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Happens on both Text View and Text Field. It also happens on a payment form created programatically by Stripe.

Comment: did you write any code to get the length of what you type in the textfield ?

Comment: No, I simply dragged and dropped onto storyboard @Pyro

Comment: Update: I just created a new view controller, and set it as entry point to app. I then dropped a textfield on it and it worked fine. I then programatically put the Stripe payment field on there and it also worked fine. Could it be to do with navigation controllers?

Comment: Update: It only happens if the field isn't in the initial view controller. So it only happens after a segue @NeilGaliaskarov

Comment: What is the text you're trying to show? I guess it came from a JSON payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I saw a solution deep in a forum, and it did actually solve the issue.

For some reason the tab bar controller I was using was causing the issue. Simply deleting the controller, and then going *Editor > Embed In > Tab Bar Controller* and re adding the views fixed it.