# App crash whenever typing in a text, unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I got this strange error using my app to crash whenever I am trying to write on a text field.

```
   -[NSNull _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108e3eaf0
   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108e3eaf0'
```

I searched for this problem, but I really don't understand why this happened?
Could any one help me?

Here is the complete error ..

```
  -[NSNull _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10450caf0
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10450caf0'
  *** First throw call stack:
 (
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042e7e65    __exceptionPreprocess + 165
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103d60deb objc_exception_throw + 48
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042f048d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
  3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010423d90a ___forwarding___ + 970
  4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010423d4b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
  5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042d3f23 -[NSTaggedPointerString compare:options:range:locale:] + 243
  6   Foundation                          0x00000001034d6e37 -[NSString compare:options:range:] + 29
  7   UIKit                               0x000000010497ee6f -[UIPhysicalKeyboardEvent _matchesKeyCommand:] + 303
  8   UIKit                               0x00000001048a33fd -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 364
  9   UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  10  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  11  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  12  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  13  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  14  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  15  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  16  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  17  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  18  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  19  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  20  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  21  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  22  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  23  UIKit                               0x00000001048a35b2 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 801
  24  UIKit                               0x00000001046b51aa -[UIApplication handleKeyHIDEvent:] + 397
  25  UIKit                               0x000000010468e838 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5469
  26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104213a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
  27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010420995c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
  28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104208e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
  29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104208828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
  30  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108449ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
  31  UIKit                               0x0000000104694610 UIApplicationMain + 171
  32  Parents-Baby Link                   0x0000000102241dfd main + 109
  33  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001066f292d start + 1
  34  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
 )
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: I added the complete error message. Plz check that out maybe you can help.

Comment: did you updated the xcode?

Comment: @Pyro yes I have them inside tabbarcontroller

Comment: @Pyro I had this error after updating my computer :(

Comment: @AmalHope can you put line of code where this crash happens

Comment: @Pyro It happened whenever I am trying to write into any textfield

Comment: @Pyro I am having two tabbar in my app and navigate through them programmatically from sign in page. The error happens only in one tabbar. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay there is one solution which may work for you, please try to put the textfield in the initial viewController and check if the app crashes if app don't crash when typing you try this:

For some reason the tab bar controller I was using was causing the issue. Simply deleting the controller, and then going Editor > Embed In > Tab Bar Controller and re adding the views fixed it. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245400/typing-in-any-text-field-crashes-app#comment60120887_36245400)

In the another problem can be the data which is passed in the Textfield is not in the valid format is may be Null or have invalid format other than string

Comment: Thank you soon much!! You saved me!! This worked for me. I didn't even know the problem was from the tabBarController!!

Answer (score 0):

If it is triggering while you are typing in a text field I would check if have some sort of target attached to the textfield such as

```
someButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.someFunction()), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

There are a lot of UIControlEvents that could be triggering. However, without example code I can only guess.

Comment: I don't know what happened, everything works fine until I updated my computer!!

Comment: `_fastCStringContents` is a private (internal) method on NSString. The issue I think is that it's being called on an `NSNull` instance, you might want to track down where that's getting introduced. Likely culprits include serialization/deserialization (to JSON or NSArchiver) as well as CoreData.

Comment: I added the complete error message. Plz check that out maybe you can help.