# swift Multiple UITextField EditingDidEnd causes app crash

Tags: swift, core-data, uitextfield

MY app crashes every time after I enter in a text to a text field. I am trying to get it to save after text has been entered and try to touch another textfield to edit but it just freezes. I am trying to use a textFieldDidEndEditing or EditingDidEnd for the text field. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is my statement.

```
//MARK: Text selected field delegate
extension ExerciseViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    var currentTextField = textFields[0]
    if (currentTextField == textField) {

        currentTextField = textFields[1]

        currentTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
func  textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print("User is editing text field")
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
    let exercise = Exercise(context: context)
    let client = Client(context: context)
    exercise.reps = Int16(todayRepsTextField.text!)!
    exercise.weight = Float(todayWeightTextField.text!)!
    exercise.notes = todayNotesTextView.text
    exercise.seat = Int16(seatPositionTextField.text!)!
    exercise.nextWeight = Float(nextWeightTextField.text!)!
    client.goals = goalsTextField.text
    client.intensity = intensityTextField.text
    client.medical = medicalTextField.text
    client.notes = clientNotesTextField.text
    exercise.exerciseInfo?.exerciseProtocol?.protocolName = protocolTextField.text
    thisAppDelegate().saveContext()
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have a crash log in the console/debugguer ? Because just seeing all the "!" could be a good reason.

Comment: Nothing comes up in the debugger but i am getting this in the console log "reason=(UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason)committed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to use `!` for casting it could crash the app. This is a quickfix to use optional values but isn't tested.

```
let exercise = Exercise(context: context)
exercise.reps = Int16(todayRepsTextField.text ?? "0") ?? 0
exercise.weight = Float(todayWeightTextField.text ?? "0") ?? 0
exercise.notes = todayNotesTextView.text
exercise.seat = Int16(seatPositionTextField.text ?? "0") ?? 0
exercise.nextWeight = Float(nextWeightTextField.text ?? "0") ?? 0
    
let client = Client(context: context)
client.goals = goalsTextField.text
client.intensity = intensityTextField.text
client.medical = medicalTextField.text
client.notes = clientNotesTextField.text
    
exercise.exerciseInfo?.exerciseProtocol?.protocolName = protocolTextField.text
thisAppDelegate().saveContext()
```

Comment: I tried this and the app is still crashing with no errors

Comment: I am getting an error of "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSLayoutConstraint text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: It's another error than before so we are making progress. The compiler is complaining about a layout constraint with a unrecognized selector. Which constraints are you setting in code or storyboard that could cause this?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36274685/5324541 maybe it helps you

Comment: Hmm ok, I'll have to try and find that